# Exit gracefully from a MATLAB programme

Tags: matlab

I would like to exit gracefully from a MATLAB programme with a key listener.
So far I came across the [event.Listeners](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/learning-to-use-events-and-listeners.html) and had the `input()` function but this latter is waiting for someone to enter a key to continue.

I have a loop and whenever I press any key, I want my program to exit gracefully instead of doing a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

My actual code looks like this, and what I would like to do:

```
while (true)
    %do things
    if (ft_keylistener()==‘q’)
       exit
    end
end
```

I would like to have `ft_keylistener` to work as an event listener and not to stop the loop at each iteration, waiting for an input as `input()`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: is it a gui or just a script/function called from the command line ?

Comment: Please see: [mcve]

Comment: @Hoki it is a script.

Comment: Thank you for the editing. I had to write this post on my smartphone, hence the first editing style.